# Wordpress REST API register_rest_route give a 500 error

Tags: php, ajax, rest-api

I want to create a class to register my custom theme rest routes. After I wrote this piece of code I've noticed that the rest api will give a 500 error and axios isn't able to get the data. I want to make a single page wordpress website by using vue to get the contents of the pages but for now I need to solve this issue. Can anyone help me? Is my code correct?

```
class Uheme_Rest_Routes {

  public static function init()
  {
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', array( __CLASS__, 'uheme_routes') );
  }

  public function uheme_routes()
  {
    register_rest_route(
      'uheme/v1',
      '/menu',
      array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'callback' => array($this, '_rest_menu')
      )
    );

  }

  public function _rest_menu()
  {
    return wp_get_nav_menu_items('menu');
  }

}
Uheme_Rest_Routes::init();
```

Comment: I've solved this issue by adding the `extends WP_REST_Routes` class and by using `__CLASS__` for the route callback since the `init` method is static. I get a 404 error for the route if I visit the page, It will tell that `there is no match...`, any fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Revised answer

*To other readers, another issue was the OP used the wrong route.*

So make sure to make the API request to the correct route, which is a combination of the *first two [parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/#parameters)* for `register_rest_route()` *(namespace + route base)*. So with `register_rest_route( 'uheme/v1', '/menu' )`, the route is `uheme/v1/menu`. Additionally:

1. With permalinks enabled, you can get a pretty endpoint URL (for the above route) like `https://example.com/wp-json/uheme/v1/menu`
2. But regardless permalinks enabled or disabled, the endpoint is also accessible at `index.php?rest_route=<route>` as in `https://example.com/index.php?rest_route=/uheme/v1/menu`

And to OP, if a callable/callback is in the form of `array( __CLASS__, 'method_name' )` (or maybe `'My_Class::method_name'`), then you need to define the class method as static (e.g. `public static function method_name()`) to prevent PHP errors. :)

And note that you also made a mistake with that `'method' => 'GET'` which should be `'methods' => 'GET'` — note the plural "methods". For GET (request) method, that `method` would work because `GET` is the default method, but if you were only allowing POST method and you used `'method' => 'POST'`, then that wouldn't work — POST would never be allowed! So once again, the correct array key is `methods`.

---

### Original answer

Your original class (without extending `WP_REST_Routes`) worked for me, after I changed the `$this` to `__CLASS__`:

```php
'callback' => array($this, '_rest_menu') // I changed this
'callback' => array(__CLASS__, '_rest_menu') // to this
```

Without that change, I got this error:

```
{"code":"rest_invalid_handler","message":"The handler for the route is invalid","data":{"status":500}}
```

So make sure you provide a *valid callable/callback* as the route handler. Or that be aware that in your `utheme_routes()` method, the `$this` is not available because you didn't do something like `$instance = new Uheme_Rest_Routes; $instance->init();`.

**Update:** You can also try changing the `'method' => 'GET'` to `'methods' => 'GET'`. And be sure the route is `/wp-json/uheme/v1/menu`.

Comment: Initially I didn't use the `extends WP_REST_Routes` but I saw that it was used in the wordpress docs and I was thinking that it's necessary to extend my custom class. I will try your fix.

Comment: Removed the extends but the error I get is a 404 `rest_no_route` . Any fix ?

Comment: Did you change the `$this`? I used the exact code in the question, only changed that `$this`.

Comment: Yes, saw also the initial comment to the answer, I have only the `rest_no_route` error now :(

Comment: Solved, I was made an error in the url I was using. Thanks for the help

Comment: I have moved my previous comment to the answer. And hopefully the extra info helps you.